# C# Xml grouping for better visualization

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this xml

```
<Group>
    <Day name="Mo">
        <title>Foo</title>
    </Day>
    <Day name="Tu">
        <title>Foo</title>
        <title>Bar</title>
    </Day>
    <Day name="We">
        <title>Foo</title>
    </Day>
    <Day name="Su">
        <title>Foo</title>
    </Day>
</Group>
```

and i want to transform this xml this way

```
<Group>
    <Day name="Mo,Tu,We,Th,Su"> <!-- notice the repetition of tuesday -->
        <title>Foo</title>
    </Day>
    <Day name="Tu">
        <title>Bar</title>
    </Day>
</Group>
```

for better visualization using `LINQ to XML`. I know that the two `xml` are not the same logically speaking but I've implemented my system not to care about it.

I've been trying to group the elements using this LINQ query

```
var grp = from d in source.Element("Grp").Elements("Day")
          group d by new { name = d.Attribute("name"), value = d.Elements("title")
           into g
           select g;
```

But I've noticed that what I obtained is kinda the same xml from which I started from.

Any idea on how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grouping by name & titles, so the only unique groups you're getting are t he ones you've already got.

You need to group your names by title, then you'll end up with groupings that contain a bunch of names that have the same title.

```
var groupings = from day in doc.Descendants("Day")
                let name = (string)day.Attribute("name")
                from title in day.Elements("title")
                group name by title.Value;
```

You can then use these to create some new elements:

```
var elements = from grouping in groupings
               let title = grouping.Key
               let names = string.Join(",", grouping)
               select new XElement("Day",
                   new XAttribute("name", names),
                   new XElement("title", title)
                   );
```

Then just create a new container for these elements:

```
var result = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Group",
        elements
        )
    );
```

You can see a working example in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X2wcQp).

Comment: the answer is useful as a starting point, but recreating the `XElement` every time become impractical if, for example, each `title` has an `XAttribute` of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication53
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<Root>" + 
                    "<Group>" +
                        "<Day name=\"Mo\">" +
                            "<title>Foo</title>" +
                        "</Day>" +
                        "<Day name=\"Tu\">" +
                            "<title>Foo</title>" +
                            "<title>Bar</title>" +
                        "</Day>" +
                        "<Day name=\"We\">" +
                            "<title>Foo</title>" +
                        "</Day>" +
                        "<Day name=\"Su\">" +
                            "<title>Foo</title>" +
                        "</Day>" +
                    "</Group>" +
                 "</Root>";

            XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);
            var groups = root.Descendants("Group").Elements("Day").Select(x => new
            {
                titles = x.Descendants("title").Select(y => new {
                   day = x.DescendantsAndSelf().FirstOrDefault(),
                   title = (string)y
                }).ToList()
            }).SelectMany(z => z.titles).GroupBy(a => a.title).Select(b => new XElement("Day", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("name", string.Join(",", b.Select(c => c.day.Attribute("name").Value).ToArray())),
                    new XElement("title",b.FirstOrDefault().title)
                })).ToList();

            root.Element("Group").ReplaceWith(new XElement("Group", groups));




        }

    }
}
```